# This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I am developing an android app in matrial design.I am trying to use toolbar as the action bar of my app.but when run app i crasging & get the errror.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

I have already gone through these links but not working 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor)    [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016847/this-activity-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor)

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base" />

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarker</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<color name="primary">#457C50</color>
<color name="primaryDarker">#580C0C</color>
```

MianActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    FrameLayout mainView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mainView=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name
        )

        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
            {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                mainView.setTranslationX(slideOffset * drawerView.getWidth());
                    mDrawerLayout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
                    mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();

            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //Set the custom toolbar
        if (toolbar != null){
             setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }



        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
     >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />

    <application
        android:name="com.example.myapp.app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
         >
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity" >
        </activity> 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` 
instead of 
`<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>` inside your `style.xml`

> style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base" />

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarker</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<color name="primary">#457C50</color>
<color name="primaryDarker">#580C0C</color>
```

Comment: `Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.`

Comment: This answer will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429951/how-to-resolve-the-error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-when-ad

Answer (score 5):

When you use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, you can delete the following two lines (the equivalent AppCompat versions are added for you):

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Comment: I think we should use `windowNoTitle` and `windowActionBar` instead, as we are in AppCompat theme.

Comment: @Jack - that's exactly what the `NoActionBar` versions of the AppCompat theme do for you.

Comment: I was stupid who didn't write that clearly. I meant to say that when you wrote two lines, instead of writing `android:windowNoTitle` you should have written `windowNoTitle`. Am I correct ?